# Separating OCR text into lines with Python

Tags: python, ocr

What I'm trying to do is create a **list** of lines from a paragraph. The width of the lines cannot exceed a established amount of width. 
Here's a class that is supposed to solve this, here's the code:

```
from font import Font

class Text:
        def __init__(self, text, limit, size):
                self.text = text
                self.limit = limit
                self.size = size        
                self.setText()
        def setText(self):
                textList = self.text.split(' ')
                self.newList = tempo = []
                spaceWidth = Font(self.size, ' ').width
                count = 0
                for x in textList:
                        word = Font(self.size, x)
                        count = count + word.width + spaceWidth
                        if count >= self.limit:
                                self.newList.append(' '.join(tempo))
                                tempo = []; tempo = [x]
                                count = word.width
                        else:
                                tempo.append(x)
                self.newList.append(' '.join(tempo))
```

as you can see I'm using another class called Font, here it is:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageFont

class Font:
        def __init__(self, fontSize, text):
                self.font = ImageFont.truetype('tomnr.ttf', fontSize)
                self.width, self.height = self.font.getsize(text)
```

There are no execution errors in the code but the result is not correct: for example,

```
from text import Text

text = Text("Art inspired apparel for Creative Individuals. Do you SurVibe?", 452, 25)

print text.newList
```

What this code is supposed to do is to create lines that are max. width 452 pixels. It should print

```
['Art inspired apparel for Creative', 'Individuals. Do you SurVibe?']
```

but instead it prints:

```
['Art', 'inspired', 'apparel', 'for', 'Creative', 'Art inspired apparel for Creative', 'Individuals. Do you SurVibe?']
```

And I can't find out what's going on. I think my loop is fine and everything run smoothly! I'm pretty sure it's a silly mistake but couldn't figure it out on my own. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (When you say text, you didn't mean "string" as people would understand, but "OCR text".)

Comment: Optical character recognition? I searched the term on Google and that was the result @smci

Comment: (Yes, OCR = "Optical character recognition", I also added that tag to this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
self.newList = tempo = []
```

Both variables point to the same list.

Comment: I'm so ashamed. That was the mistake. I can't mark this as correct answer yet "in 5 minutes". But thanks a lot. I was going crazy here. Stupid mistake.

Comment: It's one of the more annoying Python warts. Similar gotcha to initializing function args to empty-list `def func(..., some_list_arg = [])`

Comment: @smci For me it's a nice feature. You can do `result = cache[key] = foo()`

Comment: It can be nice or nasty, depending on aliasing, and whether foo() returns a  list/tuple or primitive type.